# ¿Moverme infinitamente hacia todos lados en una pagina con html, css y Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Mi duda es porque quiero implementar una pagina web que muestre varios elementos, pero te permita moverte hacia todos lados de la pagina y siga apareciendo elementos.

Normalmente una pagina siempre te posiciona arriba y a la izquierda, y moverte solamente hacia abajo y a la derecha, pero quisiera que me permitiera moverme a todos lados.

Un ejemplo en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar lo que has intentado o investigado y explicar dónde tienes un problema específico, mediante un [mcve]. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta, no muestras un ejemplo y es demasiado amplia, por no decir que se puede basar en opiniones. Todo esto es motivo de cierre de tu pregunta. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega más información a tu pregunta. Saludos